# Looking for a tutorial on ACL for a UNIX server

Tags: unix, access-control-list

Does anyone out there know of any good "how to" tutorials that can help me set my directory and files permissions using ACL in order to secure my server while providing FTP and Web access to certain files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[Managing Group Access on Linux and Unix](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html)** is a good starter guide.